# Geany themes problem

Tags: themes, geany

Can someone just give my line code that i should write into terminal i tried `~/Downloads/geany-themes master/colorschemes ~/.config/geany/colorschemes`  And showed this message `bash: /home/v4m3r/.config/geany/colorschemes: Is a directory`
My english is not good so please answer in the easiest way. I have Ubuntu 17.10 and geany 1.31-1.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I am idiot. I should just write `~/Downloads/geany-themes master/ ~/.config/geany/colorschemes`